# How can I define the width of a column (PrettyTable, Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datatable, prettytable

So, I got a table (PrettyTable) and I want to make them as wide as I want. For example, the first column should have a width of 5px, the second of 18px, and so on...
How can I do this?

Comment: No, it's not possible to define width in pixels.

Comment: are there any other options to define the width? @Alderven

Comment: You can define number of symbols with [texttable](https://pypi.org/project/texttable)

Answer (score 12):

PrettyTable's `_max_width` can define column/field width in maximum characters instead.

```
table._max_width = {"Field 1" : 50, "Field 3" : 25}
```

Specify the field names and the max characters it can fit; exceeding characters wrap onto the next line.

Fields not listed will still auto adjust to long texts.

Answer (score 1):

In PrettyTable:

`_max_width` : define a dict of column width in maximum characters.

`_min_width` : define a dict of column width in minimum characters.

To have a dynamic column width and yet define a max column width use:

```
table._max_width = {"Column 1" : 50, "Column 2" : 25}
```

Specify the field names and the max characters it can fit; exceeding characters wrap onto the next line.

Fields not listed will still auto adjust to long texts.

To fix the width of the column using PrettyTable, both dicts `_min_width` and `_max_width` would be same.

```
table._min_width = {"Column 1" : 50, "Column 2" : 25}
table._max_width = {"Column 1" : 50, "Column 2" : 25}
```